# There is an error in app.UseMigrationsEndPoint(), if this cant be solved can guide me to remove asp.net identity files (which is used to create login)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using OfflineEventManagment.Data;
using OfflineEventManagment.Areas;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OfflineEventManagment
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
                    string originalPath = ctx.Request.Path.Value;
                    ctx.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
                    ctx.Request.Path = "/Error/_404";
                    await next();
                }
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //Error
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWxHV.png)

**Can anyone help me solve this? I can't figure why there is such an error, if this error cant be solved, can asp.net core identity code can be removed? if so, how?
entitycore identity cannot create context file, also I cann't see database file for this particular project only!
***Or Should I create New Project?*

Answer (score 1):

I recreated a project and encountered the same error as you, as follows:
[image]

Then I introduced the package to solve the problem: （Pay attention to the .net version you are using）

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore`

Resutl:

[image]

For more information, please refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#usedatabaseerrorpage-obsolete

Answer (score 1):

app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();

It's under the Library below. try this.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore